# How to retrieve params from the url in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

What I am trying is  to retrieve the params from the url after ? symbol.Can anyone hep me out to solve this problem

Comment: Did you read documentation? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location Also it's not Angular specific, it's just native location object. Check `location.search` property.

Comment: yes.As i am new to angularjs i read all about it but the doubt is how to implement it in program.and have a great confusion between $routeParams and $location

Comment: $routeParams are used when you configure routes with ngRouter. $location is wrapper around native location with some additional methods.

Comment: The question is. Do you want to use the url for routing a user to a specific page sort of like http://{Site}/{Controller}/{Action}.

Or is it when you send queryparameters to the url?

Comment: the question is if i  have a url ,how to retrieve its params either it is displayed  in console or in any html page

Comment: @Naga Bhavani Let me know what are you using for routing ngRoute or ui-route

Comment: Can anyone please send me link which has example on this

Answer (score 0):

See [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) from AngularJS documentation

Answer (score 0):

You just need to inject `$stateParams` and than you can access for example Id/or anyother paramter using `$stateParams.Id`

Comment: Still I am unable to understand the concept.Can i have any perfect example for it

Answer (score 0):

It will depend upon the provider which you are using in your app.js for defining the route for your application,

If you are using,

```
$routeProvider then $routeParams."{your ID or passed variable}"
```

you can have in your controller and the JS file which you are redirecting to.

If you are using $stateProvider then

```
$stateParams."{your ID or passed variable}"
```

Answer (score 0):

JS file:
You may receive $routeParams in Your controller like this:

```
app.controller('detailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams){
$scope.trackTitle = $routeParams.trackTitle;}])
```

and your RouteProvider works like this: [See the detail page]

```
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
}).when('/page1',
    {
        templateUrl: 'page1.html',
        controller: 'page1Ctrl'
    }).when('/detail/:trackTitle', {
        templateUrl: 'detail.html',
        controller: 'detailCtrl'
    }).when('/tracks', {
        templateUrl: 'tracks.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    }).when('/contact',{
        templateUrl: 'contact.html'
    }
).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    })
```

});

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="track in filtered = (tracks.details | filter:name | orderBy: sortType : sortReverse)">
            <td><a href="#/detail/{{track.title}}"> {{track.title}}</a></td>
            <td>{{track.artist}}</td>
        </tr>
```